# Inject different services based on whether the server is running

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I want to automatically provide "stub" services for when the back end server is down. Currently I do this by manually changing a config setting, "isRunning". But for many reasons, I want this check to be done without either editing code or config files.

```
let isRunning: boolean = true;
...
  providers: [
    {
      provide: MyService,
      useClass: isRunning ?  MyService : MyServiceStub
    },
    ...
],
```

I tried using the APP_INITIALIZER injection token, so that I could "ping" the server before the application is loaded and test the result when choosing the providers. (This code is both [on Github](https://github.com/johnpankowicz/TestForServerRunning) and can also be viewed [in this Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/github/johnpankowicz/TestForServerRunning?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts).

```
function IsRunning(){
  return AppInitService.isWebServerRunning();
}
...
  providers: [
    {
      provide: MyService,
      useClass: IsRunning() ?  MyService : MyServiceStub
    }
],
```

But the problem that I have is "isRunning()" returns its result AFTER the framework has already chosen and added MyService to the dependency injector. Thus even if "isRunning()" returns false above, it still chooses MyService and not MyServiceStub.

If you run the Stackblitz, you can see that this is true from the console logs. The console.log statement in the MyService constructor is output before the IsRunning() returns.

Is there another way to accomplish this. Can I perhaps have code in the IsRunning() function that manually does the injection of the providers instead of relying on the providers array in @NgModule.

The APP_INITIALIZER token and the factory for it's provided service is implemented in AppInitModule:

```
export function pingFactory(appInitService: AppInitService) {
  return () => appInitService.pingServer();
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [HttpClientModule],
  providers: [
    AppInitService,
    { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: pingFactory, deps: [AppInitService], multi: true },
  ],
})
export class AppInitModule {}
```

And here is the code for AppInitService:

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class AppInitService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  static isRunning: boolean | null = null;

  static async isWebServerRunning() {
    logMsg("isWebServerRunning Enter");
    const delay = (ms) => new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, ms));

    // check every 50 milliseconds for change in "isRunning" status
    while (AppInitService.isRunning === null) {
      logMsg("isWebServerRunning in delay loop");
      await delay(50);
    }
    let isrunning = AppInitService.isRunning;
    logMsg("isWebServerRunning Exit -isRunnning = " + String(isrunning));
    return isrunning;
  }

  pingServer(): Promise<any> {
    logMsg("pingServer. Enter");

    const promise = this.httpClient
      .get(server)
      .toPromise()
      .then((settings) => {
        logMsg("pingServer Got server response");
        AppInitService.isRunning = true;
        return true;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        logMsg("pingServer No server Response");
        AppInitService.isRunning = false;
        err;
      });
    return promise;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the stackblitz example and I realized you had APP_INITIALIZER in `appinit.module.ts` but it must be imported in the root module (`app.module.ts`) and refactored some of your code. I created a manager module for the service along with a factory in order to init the server according to our condition.

[Here my solution on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ccbgyk-qvs9yy?file=src/app/my-service/my-service-loader.ts)

I added some folders and the explanation was written in each file as comments.

`app.module.ts`

```js
// imports omitted...

export function pingFactory(appInitService: AppInitService) {
  return () => appInitService.pingServer();
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  // MyServiceManagerModule must be imported calling forRoot on our root module 
  // this module internally handle which service will be used
  imports: [BrowserModule, HttpClientModule, MyServiceManagerModule.forRoot()],
  providers: [
    // our APP_INITIALIZER must be imported on our root module too
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: pingFactory,
      deps: [AppInitService],
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

`my-service-manager.module.ts`

```js
// imports omitted...

// this factory needs AppInitService to know if our web server is running
// in order to select our service
export function myServiceFactory(
  appInitService: AppInitService
): MyService | MyServiceStub {
  return appInitService.isRunning ? new MyService() : new MyServiceStub();
}

@NgModule()
export class MyServiceManagerModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders<MyServiceManagerModule> {
    return {
      ngModule: MyServiceManagerModule,
      providers: [
        // our service factory
        {
          provide: MyServiceLoader,
          useFactory: myServiceFactory,
          deps: [AppInitService]
        }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

`my-service-loader.ts`

```js
// imports omitted...

// our abstract class
@Injectable()
export abstract class MyServiceLoader {
  abstract printTime(): void;
  abstract getNow(): string;
}
```

`my-service-stub.ts`

```js
// imports omitted...

// must extend MyServiceLoader which is an abstract class
@Injectable()
export class MyServiceStub extends MyServiceLoader {
  printTime(): void {
    let time = this.getNow();
    console.log("MyServiceStub:printTime ", time);
  }

  getNow(): string {
    let now = Date.now();
    let sec = Math.floor(now / 1000) % 100;
    let ms = now % 1000;
    return sec.toString() + ":" + ms.toString();
  }
}
```

`my-service.ts`

```js
// imports omitted...

// must extend MyServiceLoader which is an abstract class
@Injectable()
export class MyService extends MyServiceLoader {
  printTime(): void {
    let time = this.getNow();
    console.log("MyService:printTime ", time);
  }

  getNow(): string {
    let now = Date.now();
    let sec = Math.floor(now / 1000) % 100;
    let ms = now % 1000;
    return sec.toString() + ":" + ms.toString();
  }
}
```

`app.component.ts`

```js
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { MyServiceLoader } from "./my-service/my-service-loader";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  template: `
    <h2>Test for server running</h2>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = "testasync";

  // MyServiceLoader must be imported
  constructor(private myService: MyServiceLoader) {
    console.log("AppComponent:ngOnInit", this.getNow());
    this.myService.printTime();
  }

  getNow(): string {
    let now = Date.now();
    let sec = Math.floor(now / 1000) % 100;
    let ms = now % 1000;
    return sec.toString() + ":" + ms.toString();
  }
}
```

Comment: That's terrific, thanks. I can see that it works by changing the  server URL and seeing that it switches to the other service. But, now I need to read through your code in detail and understand "why". (plus read some more Angular documentation)

Comment: Excellent! Happy to help you

Comment: Since myServiceFactory uses "new" to create a MyService (and stub), this won't work if MyService also has DI dependencies. Do you know how this can be fixed? [ When I first noticed this, I tried adding a constructor and dependency to MyService and it appeared to work. But that was only because Stackblitz was not giving a compile error. It failed when I moved the code into my project. ]

Comment: Yes, I will try to add it to the example on stackblitz as possible as I can

Comment: I did it. Check the example on stackblitz again

Comment: Perfect! Thanks again. I hadn't worked with factories in Angular 2. It makes sense that the arguments would need to be passed manually if we are writing the factory ourselves.